# .htaccess url parameter rewrite for specific page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

I have been battling for hours now and searched Google and StackOverflow, without a solution to my problem, hope you guys can help! :-)

I have a page with parameters as follows: `profile?userid=123456789`. I want it to rewrite to `profile/123456789`. This I have, but now everywhere on this page all links gets `/profile/link`. Is there any fixes to this? Thanks in advance, here comes my .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/profile\.php

RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile?userid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works for me with many configurations

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile?id=$1 [L]
```

if you want the `([^/]*)` to be exclusively number, you'll need to use PHP to rewrite your urls

Answer (score 0):

You can change your rule parameter order as below to make it work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile?userid=([^/]*)$ profile/$1 [L]
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: you need to put the parameters in reverse